# http videos not play on https site on Video.js

Tags: security, video, https, video.js

I use video.js on my site, but http://video.mp4 not plays I'm getting an error, as I realized https://video.mp4 plays without problem.

Is there any way to correct this? If I will get not secure on this pages no problem, Generally I need to play video.
you can check here for example: [https://kinogo.ge/watch/the-way-back-qartulad.html?key=gtgxawoc5gus](https://kinogo.ge/watch/the-way-back-qartulad.html?key=c2nnf4im0z8u)
and in same video with https: https://kinogo.ge/watch/the-way-back-qartulad.html?key=c2nnf4im0z8u

Answer (score 0):

No. The browser enforces that http resources cannot be retrieved from an https page. You can't disable that from javascript.

Comment: Is this new regulation? because 1 month ago it worked, no matter it was http or https